# Tornado not allowing put request

Tags: python, tornado, put

Below is my handler code where tornado is allowing to do get request where as getting method not allowed error.
i am missing something obivious?

```
class CustomerHandler(web.RequestHandler):
            def get(self, customer_id):
            data = retrieve_customer_data_from_customer_database(customer_id)
            print(data)
            self.write(data)
            self.finish()

            def put(self, data):
                customer_data = data
                data = json.loads(customer_data)
                customer_id = customer_data['id']
                update_customer_data(customer_id, data)
                result_out = {}
                result_out['status'] = True
                self.write(json.dumps(result_out))
                self.finish()
```

Comment: Your indentation is very wrong; please double check that, since that may in fact be the only problem.

Comment: sorry it was formatting issue at stack overflow side in my code indention is proper

Answer (score 1):

Check again indentation. Also, the `data` you are looking for is probably in body of the request. Here's a simple example:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import json

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

    def put(self):
        body = json.loads(self.request.body)
        # do some stuff here
        self.write("{} your ID is {}".format(body['name'], body['id']))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

And the test:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8888/ -XPUT -d '{"id": 123, "name": "John"}'
John your ID is 123
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was there was extra "/" I was using in put request url while calling from frontend, that's why method not allowed error was there. although error message doesn't suggest what exactly error is.

Hope this will help someone.